# How to get value from a select list inside a div and pass to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

I have created 2 divisions for my HTML file. 1 main Division (Animals) and 2 Sub Divisions (Mammals and Amphibians).

I want to get the values from the div tag that I selected and POST it on my PHP file.
For example, I chose Mammals, then I selected Lion.

How would I get the value of Lion and post it on my PHP file?

`<div class = "Animals" id="level1">`

```
<div class="Mammals">     

    <select class = "form-control" name="mammal">
        <option name="" value="">Select Mammal</option>
        <option value="Lion">Lion</option>
        <option value="Tiger">Tiger</option>

    </select>
  </div>

<div class="Amphibians">     

    <select class = "form-control" name="amphibians">
        <option name="" value="">Select Amphibian</option>
        <option value="Frog">Frog</option>
        <option value="Toad">Toad</option>

    </select>
  </div>
```

`</div>`

Comment: The most simple way is to add a `<form>` tag around this html, set the attribute `method=post` and then add a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an Pure JS Solution you could begin with this:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.Mammals .form-control')

el.addEventListener('change', function(data, test) {
    alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);

    //Then Post to the desired URL
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);
    request.send(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
});
```

Whenever the mammals selector is changed, the currently selected value will be alerted.

After this step you could simply pass the value in an in a request call.

http://jsfiddle.net/hvVFw/2/